# Rails 5 redirect_back with url query parameter option

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

According to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_back):

> redirect_back(fallback_location:, allow_other_host: true, **args)
>
> `:fallback_location`- The default fallback location that will be used on missing `Referer` header.
>
> `:allow_other_host` - Allow or disallow redirection to the host that is different to the current host, defaults to true.
>
> All other options that can be passed to redirect_to are accepted as options and the behavior is identical.

And `redirect_to` allows me to add params to the url just by passing them as a hash

So, why do none of these work for me:

`redirect_back fallback_location: tasks_path, allow_other_host: false, syncing: true`

`redirect_back fallback_location: tasks_path, allow_other_host: false, { syncing: true }`

`redirect_back fallback_location: tasks_path, allow_other_host: false, options: { syncing: true }`

`redirect_back(fallback_location: tasks_path, allow_other_host: false, options: { syncing: true })`

`redirect_back(fallback_location: tasks_path, allow_other_host: false, syncing: true)`

...and any other iteration on the above that I could think of.

All of them (that are valid code), just return me back without the added parameter

I'm trying to achieve this URL:
`(back_url or fallback_location) + '?syncing=true'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I get what @Kkulikovskis is saying, I would argue that the docs are confusing as they suggest I can pass additional `*args` and have them respond as they would to `redirect_to`.

So, I wrote a helper method:

```
def redirect_back_for_sync
  if request.env['HTTP_REFERER'].present? &&
     request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] != request.env['REQUEST_URI']
    redirect_to request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] + '?syncing=true'
  else
    redirect_to properties_path(syncing: true)
  end
end
```

Now I can call `redirect_back_for_sync` in my controller instead of using `redirect_back` at all.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/375a4143cf5caeb6159b338be824903edfd62836/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb#L89) for `redirect_back` you will see, that it essentially uses `redirect_to "whatever_url.com"` version of `redirect_to` method.

If you check [the explanation of redirect_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to) you can see that in this use case you unfortunately cannot pass any arguments. If this is super needed, I guess you could just override the `redirect_back` method to append params option to the url with string concatenation, but that seems like a nasty fix.

But to answer your question - what you want to achieve seems to be impossible out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

I bumped into this same issue just now. While not being able to find a direct solution, what I did was create a session and store the parameters in the session. After being redirected, my controller can grab the parameters from the session then delete it. 
Not really a "Rails way", but get what I needed.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You also just can add value to flash object e.g. `flash[:my_value] = '123'`, and then access it in the next request